# GCC C++ GTK ENTRY SET TEXT with GLADE

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glade

I have a small problem, I have used GTK with other languages but with C ++ being new I cannot find tutorials that allow me to use interfaces created with Glade and the ones I have found explain everything else.

I tried to write a code in C ++ where I have to insert a text in a GTK_ENTRY but nothing appears even following the instructions and using alternatives errors are shown during compilation.

I need to use GLADE because the software will have to work in many languages and the Glade file is customizable.

**gtk_entry.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gmodule.h>

GtkWidget   *MyEntry;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    
    GtkBuilder      *XML; 
    GtkWidget       *window;
    
    
    
    
    
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    XML = gtk_builder_new();
    
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (XML, "gtk_entry.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(XML, "MyWindow"));
    MyEntry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(XML, "MyEntry"));
    
    
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(XML, NULL);

    g_object_unref(XML);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

  
    
    return 0;
    
}
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_Write_clicked(GtkButton *Write, gpointer user_data)
{   
    
    
    const gchar *TextVar;
    
    
    printf("\n Verify Button Write");//Its work correctly 
    TextVar = "Verify Button Write"; // Work too
    
    
    //doesnt appar nothing 
    void gtk_entry_set_text (GtkEntry* MyEntry, const gchar *TextVar); 
    
}
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_Exit_clicked(GtkButton *Exit, gpointer user_data)
{
        gtk_main_quit();
}
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_MyWindow_destroy(GtkWidget *MyWindow, gpointer user_data)
{
    
        gtk_main_quit();
}
```

**gtk_entry.glade**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MyWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_MyWindow_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="MyEntry">
            <property name="width-request">100</property>
            <property name="height-request">39</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">56</property>
            <property name="y">38</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="Write">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Write Text</property>
            <property name="width-request">100</property>
            <property name="height-request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_Write_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">60</property>
            <property name="y">100</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="Exit">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Exit</property>
            <property name="width-request">100</property>
            <property name="height-request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_Exit_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">200</property>
            <property name="y">100</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: You cannot find any tutorials because:
1. **gtk** is the API for **GTK and C code**
2. **gtkmm** is the API for **GTK and C++ code**
3. your code is not C++ but shows only C (the 'cpp' extension doesn't make it C++)
4. you mixed up declaration parts and code.
5. Ask for what you exactly want: using GTK with glade, using GTKMM with glade, writing C, writing C++ or simply using GTK and some widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
//doesnt appar nothing 
void gtk_entry_set_text (GtkEntry* MyEntry, const gchar *TextVar);
```

with

```
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(MyEntry), TextVar);
```

And make sure you are compiling with `-rdynamic` flag.

Comment: You might add an explanation that the shown code declares a function but does not call it.

Comment: I use gcc Myfile.cpp -o Myfile  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lintl -lglib-2.0 
When I put -rdynamic give error command line option

Comment: Thank you very much its work without -dynamic